# Jquery Image zoom not working properly in Opera

Tags: jquery, zooming, opera

I got this code from StackOverflow:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function(){
        $('img').load(function() {
            $(this).data('height', this.height);
        }).bind('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {
            $(this).stop().animate({
                height: $(this).data('height') * 
                        (e.type === 'mouseenter' ? 1.5 : 1)
            });
        });
    });
});
```

It works in IE, Chrome, Firefox and Opera. But in Opera it only works when I first enter the page (if I type in the link in the adress bar).
I have a 4 page site and when I go to the Jquery page from an other page it doesn't zoom the pics on mouseover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [.each](http://api.jquery.com/each/) method instead of [.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/):

```
$(function(){
    $('img').each(function() {
        $(this).data('height', this.height);
    }).on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {
        $(this).stop().animate({
            height: $(this).data('height') * (e.type === 'mouseenter' ? 1.5 : 1)
        });
    });
});
```

---

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/x3UfD/2/)

BTW: `$(document).ready(function() {` is equal to `$(function() {`.

Comment: Give me a link to your site or create a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) please. Otherwise I cant help further!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wakary/x3UfD/
This is the relevant part of the page (but it doesn't work on jsfiddle)